# Error handler scene for when user enters wrong input, e.g. user enters text instead of clicking button

Tags: mysql, node.js, telegram-bot, wizard, telegraf

I've created a bot using mysql+node.js+telegraf. I've also made use of stages,wizardscenes and steps. I'm using telegraf-mysql-session to store sessions.

**Problem:**

The problem I'm encountering is when a user enters the wrong input, example sends a text instead of selecting a button. The bot does not respond to inform the user that the wrong input has been inserted.

Could you please give me sample code/suggestions/links on how I could go about this.

**What happens:**

1.bot hears 'enter details' button and enters the scene.

2.Normally the user is expected to select a button to trigger the next step, but if the user enters a text like 'yes I would' the bot won't be able to move to next step thus not responding.

```
 const startStep=new Composer()
 startStep.hears("enter details",async(ctx)=>{
     try{
         await ctx.replyWithHTML("Hello, Would you like to proceed?",Markup.inlineKeyboard([
        Markup.button.callback('Yes','okay'),
        Markup.button.callback('No','cancel'),
 ]))
         return ctx.wizard.next()
         }
         catch(e)
         {
             console.log(e)
         }
     })

const nextStep=new Composer()
 nextStep.action("okay",async(ctx)=>{
     try{
         ctx.wizard.state.data={}
         await ctx.replyWithHTML("Please enter your number")
         return ctx.wizard.next()
         }
         catch(e)
         {
             console.log(e)
         }
     })
```

**Desired outcome:**

I would like for the bot to detect wrong input and give feedback telling user that the 'input is incorrect. select a button'
The bot must not allow the user to proceed unless the 'back to main menu' button is selected.

```
if(user input ==correct)
{
//perform everything in the scene/step
}
else
{
ctx.reply(wrong input. Select button)
//ctx.wizard.back() 
}
```

I would love for this to be available throughout entire bot process.

Your assistance would be highly appreciated